# "So that people would know" vs "so that people knew"

Tags: sentence-meaning, will-would

I'm trying to understand this construction:

> You can do this like that, so that people would know what to look forward to

Context: I'm trying to give a story advice.

I can't decide whether it should be this or "so that people knew what to look forwad to." Both sound right to me. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious why you think the past tense "knew" is appropriate for actions that occur in the present/future?  Is it possible you're confusing this with another grammar?

Comment: @Andrew: "knew" would be a reasonable choice in the slightly different sentence "You could do this like that, so that people knew what to look forward to."

Comment: @TonyK Maybe if you used the past tense, "You **could have done** this like that ..." but not when the first part is phrased in the present/future.  Every time I read it I expect "know" not "knew".